# Rigging Glitch?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

I followed a tutorial on YouTube for modeling the character, but I followed a forum for the rigging. When I try to pose the right side, the left side moves with it, oppositely. When I try to pose the left side, only the armature moves.[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello, please post a screenshot of your whole interface https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/